# ELASTIC tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I know it's a common bug, but I tried everything without success.

I'm trying to update or create a document with an object that inside has some json[] and more. Let me show you, and it will be clearer.
This is the query:

```js
{
    const { id } = body;
    const res = await axios.post(
      `${process.env.ELASTIC_URL}/${index}/_doc/${id}`,
      body,
    );
    return res;
  }
```

and these is the values:

```js
{
  id: "56b49469-be70-49f8-aa8c-2cdbda1b03fe",
  V2PositionId: "985f8987-c600-463a-8e88-ee580da313ca",
  matchingTitle: "Software Developer - Template 2904",
  matchingDescription: "Also known as a Application Developer or Software Architect",
  matchingDepartment: "General",
  matchingEducation: ['Bachelor of Computer Science'],
  deleted: false,
}
```

My index:

```js
        "matchingEducation" : {
          "properties" : {
            "certificate" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
```

And when I run this, I get the following error: `object mapping for [matchingEducation] tried to parse field [null] as an object, but found a concrete value.`

Comment: Can you please share your index mapping as well ? You can get it using `GET index_name`.

Comment: Added the part talking about the education

Comment: Thanks for updating question. Please check my answer. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this exception because `matchingEducation` field is define as `object` and you are passing `text` value to field while indexing.

To resolved this issue, You need to pass document like below:

```
{
  "id": "56b49469-be70-49f8-aa8c-2cdbda1b03fe",
  "V2PositionId": "985f8987-c600-463a-8e88-ee580da313ca",
  "matchingTitle": "Software Developer - Template 2904",
  "matchingDescription": "Also known as a Application Developer or Software Architect",
  "matchingDepartment": "General",
  "matchingEducation": {
    "certificate" : "Bachelor of Computer Science"
  },
  "deleted": false
}
```

**or** you need to update your index mapping where `matchingEducation` as `text` type.

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "matchingEducation": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try that very soon and validate the question. Yea sounds logic.

Comment: Ok Sure. Please upvote and accept after your validation if it really helps you.